# Glob pattern to include files with extension except for in a specific directory

Tags: bash, shell, glob

Given the following directory structure:

```
.
├── Examples/
│   └── A.hs
├── Mooc/
│   └── B.hs
├── .stack-work/
│   └── C.hs
└── D.hs
```

What is a Bash Glob pattern to include all `.hs` files except for those in the directory `.stack-work`? I tried with `!(.stack-work/*.hs)` at https://globster.xyz/, but it didn't select any file.

Specifically, the Glob pattern should select `A.hs`, `B.hs`, and `D.hs`, but exclude `C.hs`.

Comment: If `extglob` is turned off then `!(.stack-work/*.hs) ` is a syntax error.  If `extglob` is turned on (and `dotglob` is turned off) it selects `D.hs`, `Examples`, and `Mooc`.  There is something wrong with tests that show it not selecting any file.

Comment: You want the pattern to select `.hs` files in the current directory (e.g. `D.hs`) and one directory level down (e.g. `Mooc/B.hs`).  Do you also want it to select files two, or deeper, levels down (e.g. `Mooc/Course1/E.hs`)?

Comment: @pjh No, Only in the current directory and one level deep, no further.

Answer (score 3):

Unless you have activated `dotglob` the `.stack-work` directory is not globed anyway.

Now to use the negative pattern syntax `!(pattern)` you need to enable extended globing with `shopt -s extglob`

Anyway the pattern you used `!(.stack-work/*.hs)` just excludes too much.

You could do it this way:

```bash
#!/usr/bin/env bash

shopt -s dotglob extglob

printf '%s\n' {!(.stack-work)/*.hs,*.hs}
```

As explained earlier, this is pointless when `dotglob` is not set, since `.stack-work` will be excluded anyway.

In a normal case without `dotglob`, a simple pattern of `*/*.hs` will not match `.stack-work/C.hs` because it is in a directory name starting with a dot.

Though if you need to match also in current directory, use a brace expression to provide two glob patterns:

```bash
#!/usr/bin/env bash

printf '%s\n' {*.hs,*/*.hs}
```

Or use a `globstar`:

```bash
#!/usr/bin/env bash

shopt -s globstar

printf '%s\n' **.hs
```

Note that this last one will also match in deeper sub-directories.

Finally with `extglob` optional pattern, you could also write it like this:

```bash
#!/usr/bin/env bash

shopt -s extglob

printf '%s\n' ./?(*/)*.hs
```

The optional glob pattern `?(pattern)` is an `extglob` feature. Here it allow optionally matching a sub-directory.

Answer (score 1):

Negate just the directory name.

```
!(.stack-work)/*.hs
```

Also, make sure `extglob` is on.

```
shopt -s extglob
```

Comment: The question asks for `D.hs` (in the top-level directory) to be selected too.

Comment: They are selected on my box (as `./` is not `.stack-work`).

Comment: Interesting.  I initially tested the code with Bash 5.2.  It did not list `./D.hs`, with or without `dotglob`.  Testing with Bash 3.2 produced the same result.  However, testing with Bash 4.3 listed `./D.hs`, with and without `dotglob`!  I think the way it works in Bash 4.3 is arguably broken.  Glob patterns matching plain `.` seems wrong, particularly with `dotglob` turned off.  Even if it works now, I wouldn't depend on it working in future.

Comment: Yes, I'm on 4.4.23 and dotglob is off.